# How to create at runtime a two dimensional array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I cannot create a 2D array from 2 variables (eg `int arr[i][j]` not allowed) so how would I create a dynamically sized 2D array?

The dimensions of the array are only known at runtime in my program.  The array is to represent a grid.  How would I code this in C?

Comment: C99 allows you to declare VLA - variable-length arrays - so if you have a C99 compiler and no artificial (homework) constraints on your work, you can write precisely `int arr[i][j];`.  (If you don't have a C99 compiler, it's time to get one.)  With that said, how do you plan to access the array?  You can either be hoping to use `arr[i][j]` to access an element, or you can be prepared to use a calculation like `arr[i*n+j]` to access it.  The memory allocation patterns required are quite different for the two cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to allocate a 1-dimensional array:

```
int* array = calloc(m*n, sizof(int));
```

And access it like this:

```
array[i*n + j]
```

The compiler does exactly this when accessing two-dimensional arrays, and will probably output the same code when `n` can be guessed at compile time.

Answer (score 11):

First allocate an array of pointers.

```
/* size_x is the width of the array */
int **array = (int**)calloc(size_x, sizeof(int*));
```

Then allocate each column.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size_x; i++) 
{
    /* size_y is the height */
    array[i] = (int*)calloc(size_y, sizeof(int));
}
```

You can access the elements with `array[i][j]`. Freeing the memory is done in 'reverse' order:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size_x; i++) 
{
    free(array[i]);
}
free(array);
```

Comment: I got an error with VS2010 which said that it can't cast void* to int*. So I had to explixitly cast to `int**` with `(int**)`. So that the first line becomes `int **array = (int**)calloc(size_x, sizeof(int*));` And `(int*)` at the second line.

Comment: @JaBe You have to cast explicitly in C++. But then, why are you using calloc in C++?

Comment: I'm using C++ and calling a lot of C code which I can't change. Calling it with C++ vec does not look much better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701816/how-to-use-a-stdvector-in-a-c-function

Comment: Should the limit on that for loop be size_x not size_y?

Answer (score 1):

This is a FAQ on comp.lang.c (I took the liberty to add the c-faq tag), it even has a FGA (frequently given answer :-)
See http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html, 6.16 *How can I dynamically allocate a multidimensional array?*

Answer (score 0):

In C a multidimensional array is just an array for which each element is another array.

So you need to first allocate memory for one array (the rows).  You can use the `malloc()` function which will return a pointer to the array.

Then you iterate through the array and for each element you allocate memory for the number of columns.

NOTE: don't forget to free the memory you manually allocate with the `free()` function in the same way you used `malloc()` to allocate it.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the examples show multiple (more than 2) allocations for the array; it is perfectly feasible to do it in just two allocations (error checking omitted) for an n × m array:

```
int **array = calloc(m, sizeof(*array));
int *data   = calloc(m * n, sizof(*data));

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    array[i] = &data[i * n];


...use array[i][j]...

free(array[0]);
free(array);
```