# Changing fixed bi-dimensional array to take size given at runtime

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to wrap my head around this the whole day...

The code that I have so far works as planed, the idea is that I'll have to change `tCell * cells[3][5]`; to take a size that's given at runtime. What changes do I need to make to retain the functionality?

```
typedef struct {
  int active;

} tCell;

typedef struct {
  tCell * cells[3][5];

} tGrid;

// creates a grid and initialize all the cells to NULL
tGrid *init_grid()
{
  tGrid *grid= malloc(sizeof(tGrid));

  if(grid == NULL)
      exit(127); // failed to malloc

  int i, j;
  for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
    for(j=0; j < 5; j++)
      grid->cells[i][j]= NULL;

  return grid;
}

// adds a cell to the grid
void add_cell(tGrid *grid)
{
    tCell cell;

    int y = rand() % 4;

    if(grid->cells[0][y] != NULL)
        exit(127); // cell is taken

    cell.active = 1;
    grid->cells[0][y] = &cell;
}

void remove_cell(tGrid *grid, int x, int y)
{
    if(x < 0 || x > 3 || y < 0 || y > 5)
        exit(127); // out of bounds

    grid->cells[x][y]= NULL;
}
```

Basically, `init_grid` will have to take `x` and `y` as parameters:

```
tGrid *init_grid(int x, int y);
```

But then, how do I change tGrid struct definition? Whatever I've tried so far yielded a compiler error (e.g. `tCell * cells[][];`)

On a slightly related note, how do you read "`tCell * cells[3][5];`" outloud?

Note:

- this is a C question
- I'm using gcc 4.1 to compile the code

Comment: A very important question is *"Are you abiding by the c99 standard, by the earlier ANSI standard, or by what gcc will let you get away with?"* In the first and last cases you have variable-sized arrays available to you and this is relatively easy. In the second case you're going to have to jump through some hoops that feel unnecessarily awkward.

Comment: so do you want to make the array the size of x and y?

Comment: That said, this has been beaten to death on Stack Overflow.

Comment: [This posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456640/) explains how to do what you want.

Comment: @dmckee: whatever gcc will let me do.

Comment: @TomZych: thanks! for some reason, searching for C related question yields lots of results related either with C++ or with C#.

Comment: If you search for `[C]`, you'll get only questions with the `C` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy.

```
typedef struct {
  int rows;
  int columns;
  tCell **cells;
} tGrid;
```

And allocating:

```
tGrid *pGrid = (pGrid*)malloc(sizeof(tGrid));
/* check results etc */
pGrid->rows = rows;
pGrid->columns = columns;
pGrid->cells = (tCell**)malloc(sizeof(tCell*)*rows);
/* check results */
do{
    pGrid->cells[rows-1] = (tCell*)malloc(sizeof(tCell)*columns);
    /* check results */
} while (--rows);
```

Done.

Or, you can also do:

```
typedef struct {
  int rows;
  int columns;
  tCell *cells;
} tGrid;
/*****whatever in the middle ***********/
pGrid->cells = (tCell*)malloc(sizeof(tCell)*rows*columns);
```

instead of the `do-while` loop. The difference is that in the first case, each row will be a separate array in the memory, which may be useful when handling the thing.

Of course, in the end, for each `malloc` there has to be a `free`.

Comment: should I assume that remove_cell will just need to free the cell at x/y?

Comment: on a second thought, this is not exactly the same: my *cells[][] is an array of pointes to tCell struct initialized with null pointer, not an array of tCells (initialized with 0'ed values).

Comment: @apann, just add another level of indirection.